# AC don't want to start

Tags: electrical, repair

My ac don"t want to start on its own. I found a lose wire in the furnace which I reconnected, I replaced the contactor and the run capacitor. when I turn on the ac will not start on its own. When I push the button on the contactor if fires up and runs. It just wont start on its own.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the contactor and the button?

Comment: I tried a copy and paste and it didn't work and I don't see any way to add a pic

Comment: Have you checked voltage on the contactor actuator terminals when you try to start it?  It's probably either not getting voltage or the contactor is bad or not wired correctly.